# How to get an id from the results in two tables

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

Consider an order.  An order will have one or more line items.  Each line item is for a particular product.

Given a filter table with a couple of products, how would I get the order id's that had at least all of the products listed in the second table?

```
table Orders(
  OrderId int
)

table LineItems (
  OrderId int,
  LineItemId int,
  ProductId int
)

table Filter (
  ProductId int
)
```

data

```
Orders
OrderId
--------
1
2
3


LineItems
OrderId   LineItemId   ProductId
-------   ----------   ---------
1         1            401
1         2            502
2         3            401
3         4            401
3         5            603
3         6            714

Filter
ProductId
---------
401
603
```

Desired result of the query:
OrderId: 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

davek is close.  You first have to narrow down your result set to only include items matching the filter table, then obtain your result by count:

```
select orderId 
from lineitems 
where ProductId 
  in (select productId from filter)
group by orderid
having count(distinct productid) 
  = (select count(distinct productid) from filter)
```

or using joins instead of in:

```
select orderId 
from lineitems li
  inner join filter f on li.productId = f.productid
group by orderid
having count(distinct li.productid) 
  = (select count(distinct productid) from filter)
```

I ran both through QA and they perform the same, but with a decent dataset, I'd presume the join will perform better.

Comment: Yeah I typically prefer joins over subselects myself.  Thanks!

Comment: Marking this one as the answer as it was the most complete.  I upvoted both as they lead to the same conclusion.  thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

```
select orderid
from lineitems
group by orderid
having count(distinct productid) 
  >= (select count(distinct productid) from filter)
```

might work (not sure about the `having` term, as I can't test it on my home box).

Comment: That looks like it would find orders that had the same *number* of products, not necessarily the same products..